# Orrder by en php no ordena correctamente

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ordenar

cuando pongo un `order by` se hace como en la imagen, se ordenan primero los 1 luego los 2 y asi en lugar de hacerlo de mayor a menor.

[image: .]

Como puedo hacer para que se ordenen por valor numérico?.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! sin mayor informacion, si eso es texto, esta perfectamente ordenado...

Comment: Por favor agrega si eso te genera el _sql_, _php_, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías tratar con la función natsort que ordena de manera natural.
Según la documentación de php: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.natsort.php y el ejemplo en la documentación:

```
<?php
$array1 = $array2 = array("img12.png", "img10.png", "img2.png", "img1.png");

asort($array1);
echo "Ordenación estándar\n";
print_r($array1);

natsort($array2);
echo "\nOrdenación de orden natural\n";
print_r($array2);
?>
```

genera esta salida:

```
Ordenación estándar
Array
(
    [3] => img1.png
    [1] => img10.png
    [0] => img12.png
    [2] => img2.png
)

Ordenación de orden natural
Array
(
    [3] => img1.png
    [2] => img2.png
    [1] => img10.png
    [0] => img12.png
)
```

Espero que esto te ayude.